# How to scroll right in a menu bar in appium?

Tags: java, scroll, menubar, appium-android

I am trying to scroll right in a menu bar using appium in android. Now I am using java for this and have tried the following codes:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "right");
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

and

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.press(10, 10);
action.moveTo(10, 100);
action.release();
action.perform();
```

But the problem I am facing is when I try to get the size of the page it gives the value as [2048,1440] and the element I am trying to reach is at location [2300,162]. When I try to enter 2300 and search for element it gives an error that the element you are searching is out of bounds.

[Here is a menu bar just for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBqXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to scroll into an element then i would recommend to use scrollIntoView method to scroll to the element. The hard work of finding the X,Y coordinates will be done by java script executor.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",element);
```

Comment: I tried using below code but it is still giving me "no such element" exception: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Spelling\"]"));

Comment: And also I am trying to scroll to the right side and not downwards.

Comment: The error is clear, Webdriver is unable to find the element on the page.   Could you try with contains - driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@content-desc='Spelling')]")

Comment: I tried as you have written. I am getting this message.      " Original error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to evaluate expression."

Comment: Could you try using AndroidFindBy annotation. @AndroidFindBy(xpath ="//android.widget.Button[contains(@content-desc='Spelling')]")

Comment: This is my code. I am not able to add the above code which you have suggested. Can you please complete it and send it to me.    public static void main(String[] args)  {
AppiumDriver<?> driver;
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "HT4ANJT07993");
 cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.office.hw");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.office.hwwrit");
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AppiumDriver<>(url, cap);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='30WordArt.docx']").click();

Answer (score 0):

Code is below and is compile time error free.

```
    import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
    import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class MobileAutomation {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
            MobileElement spellingButton;
            //AppiumDriver<?> driver;
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "HT4ANJT07993");
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.office.hw");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.office.hwwrit");
            //URL url = new URL("127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
            //driver = new AppiumDriver<>(url, cap);

            MobileDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

            driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='30WordArt.docx']").click();

spellingButton = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@content-desc='Spelling')]");
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(spellingButton));

            if (spellingButton.isDisplayed())
            {

         js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()",spellingButton);
             spellingButton.click();
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: But for "@AndroidFindBy" annotation. It is giving me error that Annotations are not allowed here.

Comment: I have updated the answer with compile time error free code, could you try.

Comment: It is giving me null pointer exception at run time as spellingButton is not assigned with any value. And also in the code we are not scrolling or flicking to find spellingButton. Will it work ?

Comment: @AndroidFindBy assigns the element,  sadly the annotation doesn't work as a local variable by definition. The code has been modified to use findElementByXPath."scrollIntoView" method scrolls into the element.It works.

Comment: I tried using the above code but I am getting error in the line in which spellingButton is defined. When I run the code using [contains(content-desc='Spelling)], it is giving me InvalidSelectorException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to compile which basically means the path identifier value is not correct and when I try it using the exact path as xpath=[(content-desc=' Spelling')] it is giving me 'element not found exception' which I was getting from the start. Basically, it is not scrolling to the Spelling button that is not visible to it to click on.

Comment: Seems like on initial load of the page the element is not loaded.The code expect it to be available and helps webdriver to locate the element. Are you able to locate the element in the uiautomatoreditor snapshot taken from initial load of the page without any scroll?